# tcsh alias for cd through path of a port after searching

Tags: freebsd, alias, tcsh

Now I try to create an alias for this command:

```
alias cdport    'cd `whereis \!^ | awk \'{print $2}\'`'
```

Can't find any good examples of using more than 2 commands in a sequence.

How to fix that code? Thanks.

Comment: Your general syntax looks correct. But you need to remove the filename from `$2` to get a directory that you can `cd` to.

Comment: @Barmar it returns "Unmatched `." after "source .cshrc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't escape quotes in strings in csh. You need to switch to double-quoted strings to enter those characters:

```
alias cdport 'cd `whereis \!^ | awk '"'"'{sub("/[^/]*$", "/", $2); print $2}'"'"'`'
```

I've also fixed the `awk` script to remove the filename from the output of `whereis`, so you just get the directory part.

Comment: Actually I put awk only for removing filename. I thought that print $2 (second column) from first command output is right scenario.

Comment: On my Debian system, the output of `whereis find` looks like `find: /usr/bin/find /usr/share/man/man1/find.1.gz`, so `$2` would be `/usr/bin/find`. `cd` needs a directory, so it should be `cd /usr/bin`.